# jQuery - getting table rows following a filter match

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table, rows

I have an HTML table that I'm filtering with jQuery, in order to remove rows based on the content of a cell with a certain class. The following code works for that:

```
$(function(){
    $('#data td.a1').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().match(/some value/) != null;
    }).parent().remove();
});
```

However, I also need to remove the two rows that follow each matching row. How can I do that? I'm pretty much a jQuery novice.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want [next](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
$(function(){
    var items = $('#data td.a1').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().match(/some value/) != null;
    }).parent();
    var next = items.next();
    var next2 = next.next();
    items.remove();
    next.remove();
    next2.remove();
});
```

EDIT: I misread that. You want next.
EDIT 2: If your table is structured such that the values you're matching appear every 3rd row because groups of 3 rows are logically related, you can use nextUntil to grab the next 2:

```
$(function(){
    var items = $('#data td.a1').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text().match(/some value/) != null;
    }).parent();
    items.nextUntil('.3rdRowInPattern').remove();
});
```

Also, if groups of 3 rows are logically related, you can put each set of 3 in their own `<tbody>` (this is allowed) and just remove the tbody.

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd rows contain what is basically junk output - this is produced by a legacy system, otherwise I'd change the structure at its source.

Your first suggestion was perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had to guess your HTML structure. I created a fiddle here. http://jsfiddle.net/jaC72/2/

```
<table id="data">
    <tr>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
        <td class="a1">REMOVE</td>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
        <td class="a1">hello</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the script is this

```
var removeExpression="REMOVE";

$(function () {    
    $('table#data tr').filter(function(){
        var contains=false;

        $(this).find('td').each(function(index,value){            
            contains=contains||$(value).text().match(removeExpression);
        });

        return contains;
    })    
    .addClass('markedForRemoval')
    .next().addClass('markedForRemoval')
    .next().addClass('markedForRemoval'); 

     $('table#data').find('.markedForRemoval').remove();
});
```

Comment: It works with fadeOut() but not with remove(). This is because remove takes the elements out of the document immediately, so there is no next.